# KIVY (Python) thread fails to download a file by calling an Objective C method in iOS

Tags: python, objective-c, multithreading, kivy

I'm developing a cross-platform app using KIVY Framework. My app is written completely in python. KIVY does all the dependency resolution for my app to run in iOS or Android.

Now my requirement is to download a file using NSURLConnection. If I don't need to download a file using NSURLConnection then I'm using urllib2 module of python to download file. But to download it using NSURLConnection I have to write some native Objective C code.

My app can do multiple downloads. It fetches a file from a link which has all the download links. It reads each links for download and it spawns a thread. Then that thread takes care of the download.

To download a file using NSURLConnection I need to write native Objective C code which can be called from Python. And to call a method of an Objective C class I have a handy python module named [pyobjus](https://pyobjus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

I have written an Objective C class which can download a file. But I'm running into an interesting issue.

When I'm calling the Objective C method by pressing a button of my app it downloads and all the delegates are getting called.

But when I'm trying to download same thing by spawning a thread from python and calling Objective C method from that thread, download is not working.

Here is the piece of the code that calls an Objective C method for downloading -

```
from pyobjus.dylib_manager import load_dylib, make_dylib
from pyobjus import autoclass

urllib2Wrapper = autoclass('urllib2Wrapper')
ulib2 = urllib2Wrapper.alloc().init()

NSString = autoclass('NSString')

# shortcut to mimic the @"hello" in objective C
ns = lambda x: NSString.alloc().initWithUTF8String_(x)

ulib2.openWithUrl_withMethod_withFile_(ns(self.params["--url"]), ns("GET"), ns(""))

ulib2.download()
```

I'm a beginner in Objective C. Anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: if you could please include how you're invoking `make_dylib()` (to produce `urllib2Wrapper`) that would make this a complete and excellent question (currently only shows it being imported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The reason it was failing because NSURLConnection requires little bit of extra work if called from background threads.

Please follow this link - http://www.russellj.co.uk/blog/2011/07/09/nsurlconnection-in-a-background-thread/

So, I have modified my Objective C code to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Kivy UrlRequest?

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html?highlight=urlrequest#kivy.network.urlrequest

This allows you to download anything asynchronously and all in Python? ;-)

Comment: I haven't tried UrlRequest. But I saw the documentation before. I have an SDK written in Objective C which I need to include in my XCode project. This SDK intercepts all the traffic going through NSURLConnection. So I have to download in such a way that my download goes through NSURLConnection. The requests or downloads I'm doing using urllib2 are not interceptable to my SDK because those requests are not using NSURLConnection but using Python Sockets. Do you believe UrlRequest uses NSURLConnection in the background so that my traffic will be intercept able? I'll try though. Lets see.